# Where does the concourse ci create containers to run the task? How to get into any of those containers?

Tags: docker, containers, concourse, docker-image, concourse-git-resource

Where does the concourse ci create containers to run the task?  How to get into any of those containers?

Comment: This question was asked based on information in this link  https://concoursetutorial.com/basics/task-hello-world/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fly intercept` (aka `fly hijack`) seems to be what you're looking for.

https://concourse-ci.org/builds.html#fly-intercept

An important note that the container needs to still be running on the worker. For example, if the build has succeeded or failed awhile ago, Concourse might have cleaned up that container.

If this is the case, start your build again and once it's running you'll see it as an option to `hijack` when you use the CLI.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Where is the worker in the case of tutorials?.

Comment: @UCodeIT That'll depend on how you deployed Concourse and your network layout in general. If you want to find out some information on the workers in your cluster, you can use the fly -t <target> workers -d to get all the information Concourse knows about them.

Comment: I deployed the concourse in the same way, the tutorial directed me. ( https://concoursetutorial.com/ )

Comment: Then your workers will be running on your Docker host in containers on your local machine.

Comment: Oh, I see, Thanks. You mean workers here are containers over which the jobs are run. What when there is multi-node cluster?.

Comment: At that point you would have chosen which VMs you would want workers on.

Comment: Can you explain with respect to AWS?. You mean worker is service that runs in a container on the EC2 instance(VM) and manages other containers running on the same EC2 instance
?

Comment: Worker is a go binary that runs on the VM to help facilitate job containers.

Comment: Oh Now I got it. Thanks Dwayne.